# OpenPop and Web Beacons error with GetMessages

Tags: email, intuit-partner-platform, openpop

Has anyone working with OpenPop get errors when the emails being processed have web beacons in them? I have two services that process inboxs, extracting attachments, and creates blobs for processing, but whenever an email that has a web beacon (code to single back to the mothership) the openPop dies on GetMessages.  If I forward the message right back to the same mailbox, the forward  removes the web beacon and all is well.

We had to setup an OWA rule that detects messages, for example from quickbooks@notification.intuit.com and forwards them right back to the same inbox. This automatically cleans out the web beacon, but the sender is no longer known and we cannot notify them and let them know we received their invoice.

Not sure how to get rid of the web beacons, but retain the sender.

Any help appreciated.

Here is where it dies, and what the error is:

**Errors I trap**
1/3/2017 7:47 PM: ProcessAllMessages - GetAllMessages Exception - Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length

1/3/2017 7:47 PM: ProcessAllMessages - Retrieved 0 out of 1 email(s) successfully.

Answer (score 0):

We had to move off of the OpenPop as it appears there were just some core issues handling certain mime types that came in by email. Since no one can control devices, email clients of email senders we needed a more robust solution that handled exceptions rather than quit at an exception.

We migrated/rewrote using exchange web services
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567668.aspx

it was pretty easy to migrate the code as we only had to change connections and a few basic objects. The majority of the framework we had written was not changed at all.